# マップのピンの吹き出しをコード側から消す

Tags: ios, swift

mapkitのピンに吹き出しをつけました
通常はピン以外の地図の部分をタップすると消えるのですが、コード側から消すのはどのようにすればよいでしょうか？
[image: ピン]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mapView.deselectAnnotation(annotation, animated: true)
```

で吹き出し（コールアウト）を閉じることができます。

参考）

- [開発弱者: MKMapViewのCallOutの表示・非表示 | Swift](http://imnuybtvrcexw.blogspot.jp/2015/12/mkmapviewcallout-swift.html)